# javascript - Gulp not copying images

Tags: javascript, gulp

After changing the gulp destination folder, my images are no longer being copied but everything else is... I get my notification but "images" folder is not created nor the images are copied... (I am a newbie with gulp so please forgive me if it's a stupid mistake :)

```
gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/images/**/*')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../viewer/images'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Images optimised', onLast: true }));
});
```

Structure:

```
parent

  - viewer (destination folder)
    - js (copied)
    - css (copied)
    - fonts (copied)
    - index.html (copied)
    - maps (copied)

  - p-viewer
    - src
    - gulpfile.js
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your destination should probably be just `viewer/images`. The destination is relative to where the gulpfile is, not relative to your source.

My assumption has this as your folder structure:

```
- src
  - images
- viewer
  - images
- gulpfile.js
```

Your code has this as your folder structure:

```
- parent    
  - src
    - images
  - gulpfile.js
- viewer
  - images
```

which probably isn't what you intended.

If it is, I believe there is also a security thing in gulp that doesn't let you operate in folders that are higher than the gulp file (so you can't accidentally do something crazy to your system).

Comment: You can operate outside the folder via using `{force: true}` Added folder structure...

Comment: @Devrim You said it was working until you changed the destination directory. Was it working before it it was set differently, or if you change the destination path to something that doesn't use `..` at the start?

Comment: It doesn't work anymore even if I use relative destination... The bizarre thing is everything else is being copied into the '../viewer/' folder... Just not images.

Comment: @Devrim If you comment out the cache line (so it's just a straight copy), does it work?

Comment: @Devrim So, it's likely then that your `dest` is just fine, and it's just something with the caching bit.